# unable to use angularjs service returned data in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, controller

I have data returning from a service, but im unable to make use of that data in my controller. Please tell me what is wrong; the first console.log prints the data, but the second console.log prints null; is it because of scope issues?

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.service('dataService', function($http) {
getData = function() {
return $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://www.example.com/api/v1/page',
    params: 'limit=10',
    headers: {}
 });
```

}
});

```
myApp.controller('AngularJSCtrl', function($scope, dataService) {
$scope.data = null; 
dataService.getData().then(function(dataResponse) {
    $scope.data = dataResponse;
console.log($scope.data); //Prints my data here//
});
console.log($scope.data); //prints null//
```

});

Comment: Even though the link talks about jquery ajax, it is a `generic asynchronous call` question.

Comment: Should learn basic of JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript, this is not AngularJS related

Comment: I already have the response, i need to pass this response to another http call. but im unable to use the returned response outside.

Comment: Just run it inside the then function or chain the promises... Or you can set a watch on `data` and do something...

Comment: thank you, it works when i run inside the then function :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second console log gets executed immediately as it is not waiting for the service method to get executed (remember javascript is asynchronous) so it will not wait.

```
myApp.controller('AngularJSCtrl', function($scope, dataService) {
$scope.data = null; 
dataService.getData().then(function(dataResponse) {
    $scope.data = dataResponse;
console.log($scope.data); //Prints my data here//
});
//outside service call and hence will print null with which it was initialized earlier
console.log($scope.data); //prints null//
});
```

Comment: so, what do i do now to get it working? The reason is I need to pass this response as a data to another http request.

Comment: have the other request in the getData().then this will create a dependency chain

Comment: can u plz mark the answer as accepted